# Why keeps showing this error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW  "VU_REPORT5" ("Selling Report") AS
  SELECT  a2.FIRST_NAME || a2.SUR_NAME ||', living in ' || a4.COUNTRY ||
            ', ' || a4.CITY || ' ' || a4.LINE_1 || a4.LINE_2 || 
            a4.LINE_3 || a4.LINE_4 || ', bought an ' || a1.MAKE || '  ' ||
            a1.MODEL || ' from employee ' || a3.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || 
            a3.SUR_NAME || ' at ' || a1.SOLD_DATE || ', Making a profit of ' ||
            to_char(a1.SOLD_PRICE - a1.PURCHASE_PRICE) ||' pounds.'  AS "Selling Report",
          to_char(SELECT sum(a5.SOLD_PRICE)-sum(a5.PURCHASE_PRICE)
                    FROM CAR a5
                    where (to_date(a5.SOLD_DATE,'mm-dd-yyyy') <= to_date(a1.SOLD_DATE,'mm-dd-yyyy'))
                    ORDER BY a5.SOLD_DATE
                    GROUP BY a5.SOLD_DATE) AS "OVERALL Report"
FROM CAR a1,
     CUSTOMER a2,
     staff a3,
     ADDRESS a4
WHERE a1.BOUGHT_BY_CUSTOMER_NO = a2.CUSTOMER_NO and
      a1.SOLD_BY_STAFF_NO = a3.STAFF_NO and
      a4.ADDRESS_NO = a2.ADDRESS_NO
ORDER BY a1.SOLD_DATE
```

Comment: Please format this question in a more human friendly way, and include some more details.

Comment: Start with a simpler query and gradually add more to it.  When you add the part which causes the error, you'll know where the error is.

Comment: Whenever you post something like this, please post the entire error message. For example, the message shows where (at what line and position) the error was found. Don't ask volunteers to redo the work that the compiler has already done.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the view is defined as returning a single column ("Selling Report"), but the query actually returns two columns ("Selling Report" and "OVERALL Report").

Another issue is that you can't put a sub-select into a function call; in this case

```
to_char(SELECT sum(a5.SOLD_PRICE)-sum(a5.PURCHASE_PRICE)
                    FROM CAR a5
                    where (to_date(a5.SOLD_DATE,'mm-dd-yyyy') <= to_date(a1.SOLD_DATE,'mm-dd-yyyy'))
                    ORDER BY a5.SOLD_DATE
                    GROUP BY a5.SOLD_DATE)
```

simply isn't valid. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this sub-query so I can't really advise you on how to correct the problem.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. But after changing it, the error still shows

Comment: I also noticed that you have a subquery in a function call - this isn't valid. Best of luck.